# Is Clojure a wrong choice for implementing Data Structures?

Tags: data-structures, clojure, language-choice

I am planning to improve my knowledge of Clojure and algorithms at the same time by implementing some known data structures in Clojure (e.g. linked lists, skip lists, bloom filter, etc.). However, [I learned recently](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/189796/64128) that this might not be a good idea.

> [... T]he fact that getting an optimized solution is so difficult
>   should be a sign that's somethings wrong. In the ~2 years that I've
>   been writing Clojure, I've never written my own basic structure.
>   In most other languages, it's a very common exercise. In Clojure though, the lower level implementation
>   of the structures used are best tucked away somewhere, and it's much
>   more common to just use the basic structures of the language.

This was also kind of how I felt while implementing the linked list. Of course, I know since this is only an exercise and not production code, it does not matter too much if the code is optimal or not, or there is already a better built in solution or not. On the other hand, I wouldn't want to waste time on something that does not make sense.

I know this question might be tagged as opinion-based, and therefore without a clear answer. However, imagine I asked: "Is assembly the right choice for implementing the back-end part of an average web-app?". While this second question is also "opinion-based", I cannot imagine that the answer would be "yes", (well, except maybe for some very-very-very specific edge case.) That's why I hope that my question also has a clear yes/no answer.

Comment: @Downvoters, close voter: care to explain what is wrong with this question? Do you see a way it could be improved, or is it beyond hope?

Comment: It's been answered.  See below.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Robert, I had seen it. Indeed, it does answer my question and give very good points. And I do understand that the answer is "no, it is not a good idea to implement traditional data structures in Clojure". However, I still do not see what is wrong with my question?

Comment: This site specializes in software design, not choosing a programming language (which is explicitly off topic).  My answer tries to focus on software design, not language choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditional data structures are *mutable* by nature.  You manipulate them by changing pointers/references and modifying their contents.  That's hard to do in an immutable language; you essentially have to replace the data structure with a new one.

Closure itself doesn't even stick to immutability when using its own internal data structures:

> Clojure data structures use mutation every time you call, e.g. assoc, creating one or more arrays and mutating them, before returning them for immutable use thereafter. The reason is performance - you simply can’t get as fast using only pure functions and immutable data.

Your choice, therefore, is choosing a different language for learning basic data structures, or writing them in an immutable style, in the vein of Okasaki's [Purely Functional Data Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521663504).

**Further Reading**
[Transient Data Structures](https://clojure.org/reference/transients)